# Lottie Animation in React causes Memory leak / browser freeze at rerenders

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks, lottie

I'm using Lottie to display an animation on a page in a basic Create React App with React Router. When I navigate through the page and enter the page with the animation again the animation loads slower and slower, causing the browser to freeze after a few times of revisiting the page and I can't explain why.

In my understanding, destroying the animation on unmount should be enough to destroy the whole instance or am I wrong?

This is the animation component:

```
import React from 'react';
import lottie from 'lottie-web';
import sketchAnim from './sketchAnim.json';

const AnimSketch: React.FC = () => {
  const elem = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const anim = lottie.loadAnimation({
      animationData: sketchAnim,
      loop: true,
      renderer: 'svg',
      container: elem.current,
      autoplay: true,
    });

    return () => {
      anim.destroy();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={elem} className="inset-0 absolute"></div>
  );
}

export default AnimSketch;
```

Comment: Are you sure that no parent components are causing re-render to your AnimSketch component?

Comment: @RajenderJoshi yes and a rerender shouldn't be affecting the animation or re-initiating it, as the Effect only runs on mounting :S

Comment: Makes sense and I cannot see anything wrong in your component as well. Can you just add a debugger in your effect or component body to reassure any rerenders. I have worked with 500-600kb of lottie animation files with issues at all.

Comment: @RajenderJoshi The effect was only executed when I reentered the route. Odly, when I called `anim.stop()` before `destroy` it worked fine, so I think there might actually be a bug in lotties destroy method where it doesn't kill some events

Comment: Great finding. Who knew clearing things up could mess everything.